# Plot every 2 columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df which compares the new and old data. Is there a way to plot every 2 columns, with the x axis as the date? Or plot all the columns with the same rootname against the date. So there should be 1 line graph per fruit.

```
df
    date        apple_old     apple_new    banana_old   banana_new
0   2015-01-01        5          6             4              2          
...
```

I tried:

```
for col in df.columns:
    if col .endswith("_old") and col .endswith("_new"):
        x = x.plot(kind="line", x = date, y =(f"{col}_old", f"{col}_new"))
```

Comment: There are only columns with `_old` and `_new` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df1 = df.set_index('date')

df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

for lev in df1.columns.levels[0]:
    print (df1[lev].plot())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this this set comprehension:

```
l = list({i.split('_')[0] for i in df.columns[1:]})
for col in l:
    x = x.plot(kind="line", x = date, y =(f"{col}_old", f"{col}_new"))
```